# Is there more than one way to derive an energy function from differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics, oscillatory-integral, limit-cycles

I don't know how this energy function (screenshot below) comes from the oscillator equation.  I know you can get it from $E =\frac{{\dot x}^2}{2} - \int \ddot x (x)dx$, which is conservative (meaning $\dot E = 0$), which is only point of an "energy" function in the book til this page (as supported by the second screenshot).  But, how do we know this energy function has anything to do with this diff eq?

And, why is it saying that after a cycle the change in E is zero.  That would mean it actually is a conserved quantity.  But, the time derivative of E is ${\dot x}^4$, so it is not a conserved quantity.

(Also, any editing tips would be appreciated.)

[image]

Second screenshot:

[image]

Comment: From the mathematical point of view the name is not important. Simply is a function useful to prove the proposition. A physicist, of course likes that name because it is, by definition, the mechanical energy of the system (conserved in a ideal oscillator and not conserved in a damped one).

Comment: Your question is related to calculus of variations. The "energy function" used is a Lyapunov energy function to analize the proposition. i think you will find more elaborated, precise and rigorous answers via stability of systems theory (Euler-Lagrange eqs., Lyapunov stability, etc.).

Comment: I'm sure $V(x)$ refers to some sort of potential energy, but how does your text define this?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yeah, in the classical physics context it is potential energy.  More generally, $\int \ddot x (x)dx$.

Comment: @Luciano How can it be a Lyapunov function?  The point of those is that they are not conserved.

Comment: @RafaBudría Yeah, the name is reference to what it is a generalization of.  But, I'm not sure how your comment helps with my question.

Comment: I meant that it is probable that names tricked you. Anyway, you ask "why is it saying that after a cycle the change in E is zero." It doesn't say that, it's saying that if there were periodic solutions, the energy variation (energy is only some function useful here) would be zero. So, as the energy variation is not zero, there are no periodic solutions.